# What's the mapping from Type.getSort() to the local and stack arrays in visitFrame(...)?

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I need to adapt my code to the stricter Java 7 verifier and have to add `visitFrame` calls in my MethodNode (I'm using the tree api). I could not find any information on how `Type` maps to the `Object[]`s used in visitFrame, so please help me out here...

This is what I have so far:

```
private Object getFrameType(Type type) {
    switch (type.getSort()) {
        case Type.BOOLEAN:
        case Type.CHAR:
        case Type.BYTE:
        case Type.SHORT:
        case Type.INT:
            return Opcodes.INTEGER;
        case Type.LONG:
            return Opcodes.LONG;
        case Type.FLOAT:
            return Opcodes.FLOAT;
        case Type.DOUBLE:
            return Opcodes.DOUBLE;
        case Type.OBJECT:
        case Type.ARRAY:
            return type.getInternalName();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException(type + " can not be converted to frame type");
}
```

What I'd like to know is: what are `Type.VOID` and `Type.METHOD`?
When do I need `Opcodes.TOP`, `Opcodes.NULL` and `Opcodes.UNINITIALIZED_THIS`?

I'm guessing `UNINITIALIZED_THIS` is only used in the constructor and I can probably ignore `VOID` and `METHOD`, but I'm not sure and I don't have the slightest idea what `TOP` is.

Comment: I was looking for a method like this, thanks :-), have you modified it since?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your need correctly, you could just let ASM calculate the frames for you. This will probably slow down the class generation a bit, but certainly worth a try.

When creating the `ClassWriter`, just add [`COMPUTE_FRAMES`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_FRAMES) to the flags argument of the constructor, e.g.

```
new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
```

Similarly, if you are transforming a class, the `ClassReader` can be asked to [expand the frames](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#EXPAND_FRAMES) like:

```
ClassReader cr = ...;
ClassNode cn = new ClassNode(ASM4);
cr.accept(cn, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
```

The former option has the benefit that you can forget about the frames (and "maxs") altogether while the latter option might require you to patch the frames yourself depending on what kind of transformation you do.

*The examples are for ASM version 4, but these features have been supported at least since version 3 - the parameters are just passed a bit differently.*

Comment: Hi, I can't use COMPUTE_FRAMES in my program because it loads the classes I want to instrument which leads to LinkerErrors. I'll still pick this as the answer as I no longer have this problem.